# Addressbook ios7: set website

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a button on my app that adds a contact to the user's address book. I'm already setting the name and phone number. Now, I want to set the contact's website, how can I do this?

To set the phonenumber I'm doing this:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)[person st_telephone], kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same as setting phone numbers except you use `kABPersonURLProperty`.

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"some url", kABPersonHomePageLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newContact, kABPersonURLProperty, phoneNumbers, nil);
```